# NuGet reinstall updates the package to newer version

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I have cleared all the local NuGet caches and Visual Studio 16.9 is unable to restore the packages.

It says:

> All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore.

When I build the project, I get many errors as the NuGet packages are not restored.

The project has to contain the exact same packages as they are in the *PackageReferences* inside the csproj file and I've read that using the Package Manager Console can help by [executing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages) the `Update-Package -reinstall` command.

> The Install-Package command does not provide an option to force a reinstall, so use Update-Package -reinstall instead.

I tried it and now I have this in my log:

> No package updates are available from the current package source for project....

Updates? I don't want to update anything...

> Restored D:\Dev\MyProject01\MyProject01.csproj (in 29 ms).

> Successfully uninstalled 'Acr.UserDialogs 7.1.0.475' from MyProject01

> Successfully installed 'Acr.UserDialogs 7.1.0.481' to MyProject01

How is this ***a reinstall***? Seems more like updating the package to a newer version...

How could I reinstall the same packages?

**UPDATE**:

When I use the **Rebuild** command in the Solution Explorer, this is what I see.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Actually**, that right-click on the Solution-->Restore nuget packages is for the missing project `packages` folder with `packages.config`. And it cannot detect the global cache missing packets alone.

That is why Microsoft has enabled these two settings:

[image]

So you do not have to worry about restore step. Just click **Rebuild** button rather than **Build** button. The two restore settings are under **Rebuild** process.

> The project has to contain the exact same packages as they are in the
> PackageReferences inside the csproj file

`update-package -reinstall` command is for non-sdk style projects with `packages.config` nuget management format and always reinstall the same version. And I wonder if your solution has the non-sdk project that used `packages.config` and that project can use the command.

I have a non-sdk project with `net framework 4.5.2`. See:

[image]

But `update-package -reinstall` does not work on new-sdk projects.

`ConsoleApp1` is a net core project.

[image]

**So**, I wonder if you use `Update-Package` under it. And that command is to update the old version to the new one which can works on both non-sdk projects and new-sdk projects.

[image]

[image]

**Conclusion**

When you face the problem next time, just click **Rebuild** button. It is more easier.

Comment: @Nestor,1) try to [clean nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) first or delete all cache files under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages` 2) close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder, `bin` and `obj` folder 3) try to run update-packages -reinstall again if your solution has  a project used `packages.config` format.

Comment: I don't use `packages.config`, only `PackageReference`.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your project's `obj/` directory (this is where NuGet stores information about which packages it's decided to use), and then rerunning the restore.

If you have source dependencies (i.e. `ProjectReference`) you may need to delete their `obj/` directories too